# How to run a compiled C++ code written originally for Linux in Windows?

Tags: c++

I have the .tar.gz source of a (scientific) program written for Linux. I want to compile and run the program in Windows. I compiled the program in Windows using CodeBlocks (GCC) and now want to run it.

The program has some predefined scenarios (inputs) as example, that are (seemingly) stored as .h files.

In Linux, I run them this way: (the name of the program is PROG)

```
$ \.PROG sample
```

and it shows the computed output. Now that I've compiled it in Windows how can I do the same here?

Comment: When you compile the program, it will create an `exe` file, for example `PROG.exe` in the `\bin` folder of your project depending on how your directory is set up.

Comment: I remember this question used to come up a lot but the other way around. Have times changed... :)

Comment: Well, since you've already compiled it, it should be pretty much the same (assuming the code is cross-platform and works on Windows). Open a command prompt where the binary is, and type `PROG sample` (and Enter, obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the program from inside codeblocks. You should go to Project -> Set Program Arguments and write "sample" to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when running a program on Linux I use:

`./prog`

and on Windows I remove the `./` because the current working directory is already included in the search path. On a typical linux  shell it is not, which is why you have to use `./`when the program is not in one of the directories in PATH.

Comment: It's always "included". Those shells just require `./` when calling program for safety - without that you'd be able to put `ssh` into your dir and on `ssh` call you'd run this local one instead of the global one. That requirement makes you safe from mistakes since you have to explicitly confirm that you meant to run local one. I don't know why Windows isn't using such approach.